# Remove Cinnamon read-only theme

Tags: cinnamon, theme, readonly

I have installed a new theme in Cinnamon desktop environment, but suddenly it became read-only. Where is these themes located at, for me to delete them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System themes are located in `/usr/share/themes`. Run `sudo nemo` to start a rooted file manager session, then delete the theme you want, or from a terminal `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/<theme-name>`.

Note that every file in `/usr/share` should have the read **and** write bits set for *all* users/groups, and if this isn't the case you can file a bug to the effect that a theme was erroneously installed with incorrect permissions.